# IIS config to host application from other server

Tags: windows, iis, windows-firewall

I have 2 windows Server 2012 R2

1) Application server where custom application is hosted - 
2) Web server where IIS 8.5 is enabled.

I want to host the application from App Server in IIS which is running on Server 2.

Did try connect to application/server from IIS but not able to reach to other server.

I've already allowed firewall to accept HTTP on all ports in App Server.

Can anyone suggest if any specific config needed to achieve this.

Comment: What is the application server you are talking about? Show some screen shots please.

Comment: I think ServerFault might be a better forum for such a generic question https://meta.serverfault.com/a/2604